# React Native app lags when it comes to foreground

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

When the app is sent to the background and brought back to the foreground, my app lags a lot, especially while scrolling.
I am using AppState to detect this change.
Is this a bug in React Native in android?

Any suggestions on this?

Platform: Android,
RN Version: 0.60.3

Comment: if you want to test performance, always test in release-mode.

Comment: same happens in release mode